# Node.js installation spacing issue with Linux based Device

Tags: reactjs, linux, embedded-linux, iot

We built ReactJs web application PoC that suppose to install on IoT device and will only run on intranet.

**Problem Statement:** Our Device is Linux based and have limited space. This restrict us to install Node.js on Device and without Node.js, we can't run React Application on it.

I searched for compressed version for node.js but no luck. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: You can make a production build and then copy the files it has generated to the IoT.

Comment: I can make Production build for react but Node.js is basic requirement to run react build.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions that may help you.

1. deploy your application using k3s, https://k3s.io/, and use k3s to deploy your react application or web application on your edge-side IoT devices after containerizing it using docker
2. Use ShadowNode, https://github.com/yodaos-project/ShadowNode, but not sure how stable it is at the moment.

In case if you are interested in how to use MQTT in Node.js, you may check this article for more info: https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-use-mqtt-in-nodejs